# replacing efficiently an element of a list in the same index with other a sub elements Scala

Tags: list, scala, indexing, replace

I want to add other elements to a list in the index of a given item.
for instance

`val list = List(1,2,3,4)`

I want to replace the element 3 with (3, 7) which will gives this output

`val list = List(1,2,3,7,4)`

in an efficient and generic way

here is what I tried

```
list.zipWithIndex.map { case (item, index) =>
if(item == 3) {
  list.updated(index, List(item ,7))
} else list
```

but this is not working and its not efficient in case of traversing a long list

Comment: In general, `List` is not good for these kind of operations, if you need to do this a lot, is better to use a `Vector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list.take(index) ++ List(7) ++ list.drop(index)
```

See answer linked in comments for more efficient version using `splitAt`